# Flutter app restarting when orientation changes only on Android

Tags: flutter

I have a fairly large app that I am building in Flutter for both Android and iOS.

I currently have an issue where the app does a full restart when rotating the device, only on Android. On iOS it works fine?

I have tried to see if it does the same on the default counter app but it rotates and keeps state fine there.

I can't reproduce the issue on the default counter app.

I have had a look at the manifest to see if there is anything weird there but it all looks fine to me, I did see that the `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"` changes tag was missing, so I re-added it but to no avail?

I have no clue why my app would work fine on iOS but not on Android? Coming from a native Android dev, I do know Android can be a bit of a pain to handle rotations.

Does anyone have any idea where I can start looking to find the culprit?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
        android:label="Some app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
                android:resource="@xml/network_security_config" />

            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.someapp.app

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

Flutter Doctor:

```
❯ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H1217 darwin-x64, locale en-ZA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.58.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Sounds like the app is not actually just "restarting", but crashing and then restarting. Aren't you able to get anything from logs?

Comment: nah, there are no crashes in the logs. Whats weird is its only happening on Android and not iOS. So in theory, wouldnt it crash on both ecosystems